# How to initialize a C++ global mutex in a thread safe way

Tags: c++, multithreading, static, initialization, mutex

Trying to use a function static mutex to make code thread safe. The problem is not all compilers initialize function static variables in a thread safe way.

```
void Initialize()
{
  static Mutex L;   // can't be initialized at compile time because constructor calls CreateMutex()
  L.Lock()
  // call thread unsafe code
  L.Unlock()
}
```

Here are solutions already considered:

1. Declare Mutex in global scope so that initialization happens before main(). Unfortunately, this doesn't work when there's a global variable whos constructor calls Initialize() because in C++ there's no guarantee about the order global variables are initialized
2. Use atomic operations

`void Initialize()
{
  static volatile uint16_t lock=0;   // trivial initialization can happen @ compile time
  while (AtomicExchange(lock,(uint16_t)1)!=0);  // swap lock with 1 and return previous value
  // call thread unsafe code
  lock=0;
}`

This works but has the disadvantage of busy waiting

3. Use pthread's compile time initializer

   pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

Unfortunately, this is for Windows, and we're trying to avoid using pthread

Appreciate a solution that's *portable*. I know in C++ 2011, function static initialization is thread safe, but we're avoiding C++ 2011 because some embedded platforms might have unreliable C++ 2011 support.

Comment: Volatile is not about threadsafe.  You can using https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/atomic

Comment: There is probably no "portable" way before C++11, since thread is first introduced to C++ in 2011.

Comment: 4. Create mutex outside of the function, pass it as function parameter / part of the context.

Comment: Clearly that `Initialize` need to access other global state (otherwise you won't need to lock it). Why you think that "Declare Mutex in global scope" doesn't work due to unordered initialization, while other global states will be properly initialized?

Comment: @felix boost.thread was available for a long time before C++11

Comment: @Cubbi I'm afraid that boost isn't that "portable" among embedded platforms. Zhang is asking for a portable way for those implementations which are largely conformant with pre-C++11 standard, not a portable way among those platforms which are supported by boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the solution to your problem is to use a nifty counter idiom. This idiom is very well described here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Nifty_Counter.

Using this idiom `std::cout`, `std::cerr`, `std::clog` streams are initialized. The only requirement is that you need to properly calculate the alignment of created type. Using that alignment you need to create a global buffer. Using that buffer the instance of the desired type with the placement new operator can be created. Boost and Modern C++ (>= C++11) have `(std|boost)::aligned_storage` template classes to create a properly aligned buffer for you. Please refer to:

- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/aligned_storage
- https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/aligned_storage.html

Modern versions of C++ feature the `alignof` operator, which can be used to calculate the alignment of a particular type. In boost you need to use a type trait `alignment_of`: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/alignment_of.html. `alignment_of` type trait is also part of STL in modern C++, but in that particular case `alignof` operator is simpler to use.

Comment: Neat trick, but I realized if that the mutex I'm using could almost be used anywhere (e.g. for memory allocation), meaning the reference counter class would have to be put into every translation unit. I still seek a compile time initialization solution

Comment: Probably I misunderstand something, but ref counter is incremented in every translation which includes the header. Buffer being used in placement new was allocated at "compile time" or more exactly at load time from the global memory store and not from heap or free store.

Comment: I didn't say the solution didn't work. I just said it was cumbersome because almost any file could have global variables whos constructor calls the special memory allocator and therefore require that reference counter to initialize the mutex

Comment: You could create that reference counter in some header file (as a global static variable) so that it's in every compilation unit. But the linker might strip it out as unused

Comment: IMO I cannot imagine that linker strips out reference counting. This would break application logic.